# How can I specify gradle project properties in gradle.properties file?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Is it possible to specify project properties such as **name** in **gradle.properties** file so will be possible to access them from **build.gradle** by using **project.name**?

I've tried with no luck:

```
name=some
project.name=some
org.gradle.project.name=some
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it.

For example in your **root** `gradle.properties` file you can have:

```
VERSION_NAME=2.0.2
```

Then in your build.gradle file (in the **root** folder) you can have for example:

```
allprojects {
    version = VERSION_NAME
}
```

If you would like to use it in your **module** `build.gradle` file you can have:

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        versionName project.VERSION_NAME  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These properties won't be set automatically - see the [docs](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties). It can be done with `settings.gradle`.