# The use Gradle properties in build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29393536/how-can-i-specify-gradle-project-properties-in-gradle-properties-file), official Gradle [reference](https://docs.gradle.org/4.8/userguide/build_environment.html) and migration [guide](https://guides.gradle.org/migrating-from-maven/), and I still cannot figure out why the following build script doesn't work.

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.14.3'    
}

def t_threads = test_threads

test {
    useTestNG() {
        setParallel('methods');
        setThreadCount(t_threads)
    }
    maxParallelForks = t_threads
}

task printProps {
        println test_threads
}
```

My `gradle.properties` file:

```
test_threads = 1
```

`gradle printProps` fails on the line `setThreadCount(t_threads)` with the exception: *Could not find method setThreadCount() for arguments [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29393536/how-can-i-specify-gradle-project-properties-in-gradle-properties-file) on object of type org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGOptions*. If I change my code to `def t_threads = 1`, then `gradle printProps` finishes without an error displaying `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is quite simple. `setThreadCount` expects `Integer` as a parameter, but property is a `String`, so all I had to do is convert `String` to `Integer` using `test_threads as Integer`.